# I have a problem with scopes in Python, Variable declared as global but still get err

Tags: python, variables, scope, global-variables, local

even after declaring a variable as global

```
import random

def wordRandomizer(categorie):
    randomNum = random.randint(0, len(categorie))
    #Picks a random number to pick a word from the list
    choosenWord = categorie[randomNum]
    #actually chooses the word
    global hidden_word
    #Globals the variable that I have the problem with
    hidden_word = "_" * len(choosenWord)
    return choosenWord

def wordFiller(word,letter):
    hidden_wordTemp = hidden_word.split()
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] == letter:
            hidden_wordTemp[i] = letter
        else:
            pass
    hidden_word = ''.join(hidden_wordTemp)
    print(hidden_word)

wordFiller(wordRandomizer(['book', 'bottle', 'door']), 'o')
```

The Error output is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amitk\OneDrive\School\2018-2019 ט\Cyber\Hangman.py", line 295, in <module>
    wordFiller(wordRandomizer(['book', 'bottle', 'door']), 'o')
  File "C:\Users\amitk\OneDrive\School\2018-2019 ט\Cyber\Hangman.py", line 286, in wordFiller
    hidden_wordTemp = hidden_word.split()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hidden_word' referenced before assignment
```

For some reason it says that the local variable was referenced before assignment even though it was assigned and "globaled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hidden_word` inside the wordFiller function is still a local variable to that function. Try also making it global in that function.

```
def wordFiller(word,letter):
   global hidden_word
   hidden_wordTemp = hidden_word.split()
   // etc
```

Also, the `randint(start, end)` function is inclusive of start and end so potentially you can generate the end value. That will be outside the scope of your array. Try this instead.

```
  randomNum = random.randint(0, len(categorie) - 1)
```

And finally, `split()` is probably not doing what you think it is. If you want a list of characters then use `list(str)` instead.

```
 hidden_wordTemp = list(hidden_word)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked everything out! and as soon as I ran the program got the out of range error so your comment was very helpful! Thanks for mentioning the `.split()` I'll look into it! Again Thanks a lot, solved

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message states, you referenced `hidden_word` before you assigned it.

```
def wordFiller(word,letter):
    hidden_wordTemp = hidden_word.split()
```

Inside the scope of `wordFilter` you never initialized `hidden_word`. Make sure to initialize your variables before you use them.